# how can I prevent prettier/eslint wraps return JSX code in parentheses?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, prettier

my code is like below:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
   return <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
   </>
}

export default App
```

but when I press `CTRL + S` for applying prettier/eslint config, it changes like below, how can I prevent prettier to wrapping my return JSX code to parentheses?

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
   return (
      <>
         <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
   )
}

export default App
```

Comment: The whole point of prettier is to be opinionated.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I also want to disable it but can't find it in prettier options.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu no yet